# Unable to test Ubuntu Touch applications on ubuntu-emulator (ubuntu-sdk)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, crash, sdk

I've followed every step of the Ubuntu SDK documentation, as detailed [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/). I am able to create different types of projects, compile and test them on my desktop. I am also able to run the Ubuntu Touch emulator perfectly, and I can launch it from the IDE which detects everything fine. I used the feature to automatically create the 'kit' for my application, in order to run it on said emulator.

The problem arises when I try to run my applications (tried several, HTML5, QML) on the emulator. It immediately crashes my entire system, to the extent that I cannot switch to another virtual console or log in via SSH from another computer. I have tried this on another machine, and I get the same result. Please help!

Details of my setup:

- Using Ubuntu 14.04
- Enabled hardware virtualisation in the BIOS
- Using the emulator and sdk from the repository: ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
- Architecture is i386 for the emulator, and I have plenty of disk space and RAM for it.
- Will add any additional information upon request

Below is the end of my syslog, as it crashed. There are many more click-chroot-agent lines above the ones shown below. The kvm virtual cpu0 disabled line also appears when the emulator is started, and it doesn't crash here as the emulator runs flawlessly. It is the last log entry before the ones that come after reboot.

Jun 28 12:05:42 big click-chroot-agent[3466]: Debug: Request to spawn session  "ubuntu-sdk-15.04" "i386"  (chrootagent.cpp:89, QString ChrootAgent::spawnSession(const QString&, const QString&))
Jun 28 12:05:42 big click-chroot-agent[3466]: Debug: Chroot session is valid  (chrootagent.cpp:377, bool ChrootAgent::validateClickSession(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&))
Jun 28 12:05:47 big schroot[3906]: [click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-507a9156-8534-4055-8a0f-0aab5f9bd026 chroot] (schmonit->root) Running command: "env LC_ALL=C apt list --upgradable"
Jun 28 12:06:10 big kernel: [ 1971.039532] kvm [4035]: vcpu0 disabled perfctr wrmsr: 0xc1 data 0xabcd

Comment: Anything interesting in /var/log/syslog*? How it crashes? What do you see on the screen?

Comment: I've added the syslog in my post. As soon as I "run" the project on the emulator (Ctrl-R) the system becomes completely unresponsive to input, what is displayed remains exactly how it was before trying to deploy and run the program.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a VM?

Comment: Nope, Ubuntu 14.04 is my one and only OS on this machine.

Comment: I would advise updating to 15.04, or if you are brave, to the latest beta/alpha of 15.10. I have found that more problems with developing seem to arise when you stick on 14.04, and it is not something picked up by the devs as they are all running the latest version.